# Javascript slider errors in console and not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The page works fine, but the slider doesn't slide to the next image.
JSFiddle makes it work out fine and the images slide, yet on localhost or any live website it fails.

```
<script>

    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides.klant');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

function nextSlide(){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'klant';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'klant showing';
}


</script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="ads">
<ul id="slides">
    <li class="klant showing"><img src="img/first.jpg"></li>
    <li class="klant"><img src="img/second.jpg"></li>
    <li class="klant"><img src="img/third.jpg"></li>
    <li class="klant"><img src="img/fourth.jpg"></li>
    <li class="klant"><img src="img/fifth.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined" on the `slides[currentSlide].className = 'klant';` part of the function but can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Please take a care look at timing. Your script in `head` is executed before `body` exists.

Comment: Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`))

Comment: Move your script tag to the end of your document before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input from Teemu(see comments below), the major issue is that your script is loaded before the HTML. Thus, the elements are undefined at the point the script ran. Wrapping the script in an `onload` event should solve the problem and putting a space between `#slides` and `.klant` in your script. See below example:

```
<script>

window.onload = function () {
   var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .klant');
   var currentSlide = 0;
   var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);


function nextSlide(){
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'klant';
        currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'klant showing';
    }

 }

</script>
```

Comment: This is magic, how would `getElementsByClassName` method find elements which are not even created yet?

Comment: They are created. See the HTML in the question

Comment: They are certainly not created, do you see `</head><body>` pair in the HTML? How is the script placed related to `<body>`? What is guaranteed to be executed before anything else in a HTML document? Where is `slides` defined? When it is referred?

Comment: @Teemu You also need to understand that there's a delay. This gives room for the HTML to be fully loaded and `slides` will definitely have values when `nextSlide()` is fired.

Comment: Like I said, this is magic. The point is, that your code actually works, I just wanted you to explain why (didn't vote down either). What is the difference between OP's code and yours? `querySelectorAll()` returns a static HTMLCollection whereas `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection, which is updated when the DOM changes. At the time this collection is defined, it's empty, but the live collection contains the elements at the time it is used. The static collections stays empty, and gives an error. (Not worth of mentioning, that the selector in OP's code should be `#slides .klant`.)

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the input. I really understand now why it was magical :)

Answer (score 1):

the script executes before the page finished loading, so the `querySelectorAll` returns an empty array. copy your script to the end of the `<body>` and it will work fine.

On JsFiddle it works because by default script executes there after load.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just Replace
 line var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides.klant');

with

    var sliderparent = document.getElementById('slides');
var slides = sliderparent.querySelectorAll('.klant');
```

Comment: yes, right have to replace whole script tag in bottom of page, Thank @Teemu